# How to return the result of a Solidity view method from a javascript function?

Tags: web3js, web3js-v1.x

I want to determine a view function of a smart contract result in web3js 1.x

Suppose we have a view function `getName(uint code)` and want to get the name of a person having his code. So we write:

```
contract.methods.getName(code).call(option)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

We want to define a function to return the result name and do something with it.

How can we relate the defined function and method call?

For example:

```
async function name(code) {
  contract.methods.getName(code).call(option)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
  return ???
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  let x = name(i);
  // Do something with x, for example:
  alert(x); 
}
```

Comment: just learn about promises, the return result is in `.then((result) => {})`

Comment: I know that the result is accessible in `.then` but I need the result to be returned from `name` function. How can I access it inside the `name` function? @rstormsf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared you function as `async`, but you didn't make use of the `async/await` pattern.

```
async function name(code) {
  return await contract.methods.getName(code).call(option);
}
```

You don't need to use `.then`. I am not quite sure but the return value is some sort of JSON object with more data than you actually need. I think you can manage on you own which properties you want.

Comment: This solution in not usable in the `for` loop given in the question (an `await` is required in each iteration, and the entire loop needs to be placed in an `async` function).